# iOS storyboards: Automatic transition from one scene to another after 5 seconds

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

So almost 70 apps later I am trying out storyboards for the first time...

I think I got the basic flow working, having a nav controller stack with segues pushing or modally displaying the next scenes, and unwinding from those. All of this without any code, except for the unwinding.

How would I make a splash screen (after Default*.png) that automatically transitions to the next scene after 5 seconds? (preferrably as much done in Interface Builder as possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set up your scenes and define your segues between them via the storyboard
2. In each view controller, set up an `NSTimer` to call the following method after 5 seconds:

> -(void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender